# Is looping through all style sheets and classes a good idea in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JavaScript function as given in code below, in an ASP.Net WebForms page i.e. in an aspx page.

The code implements the logic I need in my app i.e. to find a css class, but I am concerned that if there are many style sheets/classes then there could be too many iterations done resulting in slower performance on client-side.

In this code, first all style sheets are obtained, and then for each style sheet all classes are obtained which are then iterated to find a given class.

**Question**: Is this concern about slow performance valid when there are too many style sheets/classes, and if yes, is there a quicker way to find a css class using JavaScript?

```
function getStyle(className) {

var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;
for (var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++) {
    var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
    var classesLength = classes.length;
    for (var x = 0; x < classesLength; x++) {
        if (classes[x].selectorText === undefined) {
            continue;
        }
        if (classes[x].selectorText == className || classes[x].selectorText.indexOf(className) >= 0) {
            if (classes[x].cssText) {
                return classes[x].cssText;
            } else {
                return classes[x].style.cssText;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I am providing some code from my app to illustrate the use of above JavaScript method. I have no control over which classes are being used since they are coming from some third-party controls in the ASP.Net page.

```
 if ("none" === getStyleAttribute(getStyle(".rwDialog"), "background-image")) {
                        allDivs[i].style.paddingLeft = "5px";
                    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna work with special rules like animation keyframe or even nested class with a combination with element selectors.

Comment: @TaoP.R., I am only trying to search for simple classes like '.class1' or '.class2', and not more complex CSS rules that are in newer versions of CSS. It works for such a requirement as I have found so far.

Comment: Why do you need the style, and what is it used for?

Comment: @JayHarris, I need to get the indivdual rules within a class, and then apply some custom logic in JavaScript. For example, if '.class1' has a rule of 'background-image:none' then I need to run some custom JavaScript code.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the logic, so i can help u rewrite your code. So a rule triggers an action. can you give an example of what the custom code is doing

Comment: Load the css via xhr (it's likely in the cache) as text file and do a plain textual search? (or regex/simple parsing if rule names could collide with rule definitions)

Comment: @K3N, Could you please post some sample code as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @K3N: No, why would one do that? The styles are already loaded and parsed by the browser. No need to write an errorprone regex for this.

Comment: @JayHarris, Please look under UPDATE 1 for how I am using this method.

Comment: I think, this question should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using really long *I think fool-proof by supporting strings and stuff* RegExs you can try:

```
function getItem(selector, item, sheet) {
    var group    = sheet.substr(sheet.indexOf(selector)).match(/{(?:(["'])((?:(?=(?:\\)*)\\.|.)*?)\1|[\s\S])*?}/)[0];
    return group.substr(group.indexOf(item)).match(/\s*:\s*((?:(?=(["'])((?:(?=(?:\\)*)\\.|.)*?)\1).*|.)*?);/)[1].trim();
}
```

Now put this at the very beginning of your document:

```
function loadStyleSheets(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Now:

```
loadStyleSheets("path/to/style/sheet", function (text) {
    alert(getItem('.class1', 'background-image', text));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea in principle as it relies on custom "parsing".

Instead, I'd suggest using built-in introspection methods like:

```
var rwDialogElement = ...;
window.getMatchedCSSRules(rwDialogElement);
```

Comment: My aim was to search for certain classes and then parse for rules within the found class as mentioned in UPDATE 1. So I already have a known list of classes like 'class1', 'class5' etc., and I need to find the individual css rules within each of these classes using JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, using getMatchedCSSRules might provide a possible solution in my case, plus, I am assuming its going to be very fast since it is  getting classes for a single element. I will update later once I have tried it out in detail.

Comment: `getMatchedCSSRules` is not standard, the [mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438278) for implementing it didn't go anywhere, [has been deprecated](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/fd-QLCiLESQ/_mfowSsRR8oJ) on Chromium, and there is an [open bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79653) to remove it from webkit.

Comment: @Oriol,  Thanks for the tip else I would be spending time on this approach.