# Add a #id to all the classes in a large CSS file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a large CSS file (custom boostrap library). I need to add the class #page before every class including in the media queries, is there an easy way to do this?

Or make Boostrap only apply inside a single DIV

Ben

Comment: I think it will be faster to do it manually than writing a parser doing the job ... unless we talk about thousands of lines, and if, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830907/is-looping-through-all-style-sheets-and-classes-a-good-idea-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

use `LESS`

You can make **Boostrap only apply inside a single DIV or add the class `page` before every class including in the media queries** by using `less`.

1)[Install Less](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage)

2)create a less file(style.less)

```
.page {  //class name
  @import (less) "bootstrap.css";
}
```

also add `bootstrap.css`

**File Structure**

root/style.less

root/bootstrap.css

3)In terminal/cmd move to `root` folder execute following command

`lessc style.less bootstrap.css`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/amoxa428/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to encapsulate anything that the bootstrap is supposed to style in an iFrame. The iFrame would import the bootstrap stylesheet, the containing page would not.

You could put this iFrame inside the #page div.

Comment: Yes I look at this not going to work, was hoping there might be a trick with Note++ or similar?

Comment: Ahh I mean I would just write a script to tokenize the CSS file character by character. Every time you find a selector, you print out "#page " + the selector, otherwise you just print out the token. Every whitespace character would be printed out as itself.